# How to change language automatically when prompted for a password?

Tags: keyboard, password, keyboard-layout, authentication

I have 2 languages (English and Lithuanian) on my system, and my password contains numbers for which I use the dedicated number row (above the letters) on my keyboard. It happens that the Lithuanian language keyboard uses that number row for special letters. So when prompted for a password I usually make a mistake, because the language is set to Lithuanian. How can I automatically change the language to English when prompted for a password?

Comment: Is this when logging in or when you are logged in and want elevated permissions (`sudo`) or in some other cases?

Comment: Try to replace `sudo programname` with `LANG=C sudo programname` -- If it helps, you could make an alias for it: `alias sudo='LANG=C sudo'` and put it into the configuration file `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @sudodus: Nope. locale and keyboard layout are two separate things. Changing locale does not affect typing behavior.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I stand corrected. I thought that since the output by `sudo` was changed to English also the input would be changed in a corresponding way. Please advice what to change instead (what you think is a good solution). Maybe a small function with `setxkbmap us` if it is a system with a graphical desktop environment?

Comment: @sudodus: I don't have a solution. Something with `setxkbmap`, as you mentioned, might help, but how would that be triggered by a password prompt? And wouldn't the desired behavior in that case be that it returns to the original layout once the password has been entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dialogue with Gunnar Hjalmarsson in the comment field I think the following shellscript should work in order to run programs with elevated permissions. It will use US English keyboard when you type the password, and reset the keyboard to your own keyboard directly after that.

You can use the name `mysudo` or if you wish a shorter (but unique) program name.

```
#!/bin/bash

curkeyb=$(setxkbmap -query|grep 'layout:'|sed 's/.* //')
setxkbmap us
sudo echo "sudo $@"
setxkbmap "$curkeyb"
sudo "$@"
```

Make it executable and copy it to a directory in `PATH`, for example

```
chmod +x mysudo
mv mysudo /usr/local/sbin
```

and then you can use it instead of `sudo`

Examples:

```
mysudo nano hello.txt
mysudo -H gedit hello.txt  # remember -H with GUI programs
mysudo parted -ls
```

Explanation:

1. The shebang tells that `bash` should be used to run the shellscript.
2. The original keyboard setting is saved.
3. The keyboard is changed to US English.
4. `sudo` is started, and if not run recently, it will ask for password.
5. The keyboard is reset to the original setting.
6. The previous `sudo` command gave the shell elevated permissions for some minutes. This means that the real command can be run with the original keyboard *and* elevated permissions without asking for password (again).

If you install and run `onboard` you will see how the keyboard changes so that the top row of keys will map the numbers 1 2 ... 9 0 when the system is waiting for the password, and then changes back to your lanaguage.

Comment: Nice idea! :) Haven't tested, but it seems to work for `sudo`. However, `sudo` isn't the only thing which prompts for a password. Applications tend to make use of `pkexec` nowadays, for instance. (As regards `sudo` there is always the option to disable the password prompt for your user. But that might be an answer to another question...)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, Yes, I know that this will only work in some of the possible cases. Let us wait for feedback from the original poster, MartinSmith.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Yes I edited the line, but from using the last line because that did not work in the developing version (I put the quote characters around `layout:' at once). But my edit may have caused confusion. Sorry for that. Anyway, does it work now? And is it enough, or do you need something else?

Comment: For some reason line `curkeyb=$(setxkbmap -query|grep 'layout:'|sed 's/.* //')` when copy pasted appeared as `curkeyb=$(setxkbmap -query|grep layout:|sed s/.* //)`. I got frusturated for a couple hours :D

Comment: @sudodus ya it works like a charm, also for that error i learned a lot about bash shell scripting

Comment: @MartinSmith, I am happy that I could help you :-)

Comment: @sudodus as Gunnar said I also wanted to change the language for applications (when prompted by `pkexec` ). Do you have any ideas how to alter `pkexec`?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I see that you want that too. Unfortunately I don't know `pkexec` well enough to solve that problem. What happens if you try to run such an application via `mysudo -H application-that-wants-pkexec` ?

Comment: this option allows me to use terminal more I like it, thanks for the help <3

Comment: @MartinSmith, You are welcome :-)